# Undefined method `has_attached_file' with paperclip 2.3.8 gem for Rails 2 using Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to use the paperclip plugin in my rails app to upload images for posts. I am using Rails 2.0.2 and ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 10.04 os for project specific purposes.

I am referring to the following tutorials for this :-

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?view=comments
2. http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html

I did a git clone on the paperclip plugin via:- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip , but the command like `ruby script/generate paperclip group_post photo` didn't generate a migration for it. I then created a migration for the same through ruby script/generate and uploaded the appropriate columns of my table `group_posts`.

I then tried to install the gem and since I am using activerecord and activesupport 2.0.2 I used paperclip 2.3.8 gem from rubygems.org.The undefined method error still persisted, I really couldn't figure out why.

Now here.. the command  `ruby script/generate paperclip group_post photo` worked perfectly fine for me.

The current error I am getting exactly looks like this:-

```
undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0xb67119f0>
```

A funny thing that I observed wrt this behavior was when I made use of IRB, `require 'paperclip'` returned `true` but I wonder why they can't detect the method that comes along with the plugin in my rails app.

The **Application Trace** for the same is:-

```
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1532:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'
app/models/group_post.rb:9
app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:27:in `show'
```

The **Full Trace** for this just in case is:-

```
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1532:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'
app/models/group_post.rb:9
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_file'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `load_file'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:94:in `require_or_load'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing_not_from_s3_library'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:465:in `const_missing'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:471:in `send'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:471:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:27:in `show'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1158:in `send'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1158:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:697:in `call_filters'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:689:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:199:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:678:in `perform_action'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:33:in `cache'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:677:in `perform_action'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:685:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:123:in `process_without_test'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:15:in `process'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:388:in `process'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:171:in `handle_request'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:115:in `dispatch'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:126:in `dispatch_cgi'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:9:in `dispatch'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
/home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
/home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

My groups_controller.rb show method looks like this, here line 27 is `@group_post = GroupPost.new(params[:group_post])` :-

```
  def show
    @investor_group = InvestorGroup.find(params[:id])
    @members = @investor_group.activated_members
    # code taken from discuss method
    investor_id = session['investor_id']
    @investor = Investor.find(investor_id)

    @members = @investor_group.activated_members

    unless @current_user.is_an_existing_member_of_group(@investor_group)
        flash[:notice] = "Please join this group to participate in discussions"
        redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @investor_group and return
    else
       @group_post = GroupPost.new(params[:group_post]) # line 27, tried GroupPost.create also.. seems to be of no avail..
    end
    #@group_post = GroupPost.new(params[:group_post])
      @group_post.investor_group_id = @investor_group.id
      @group_post.post_by = investor_id
    unless @group_post.message.blank?
      if @group_post.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfull'
     else
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was not successfull'
      end
       #redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @investor_group and return to change.. appropriately....
    end
    #if @group_post.message.blank?
    #  flash[:notice] = 'Post can\'t be blank.'
    #end
    @group_all_posts  = GroupPost.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'investor_group_id = ?', "#{@investor_group.id}" ], :order => 'created_at DESC')
    # code taken from discuss method
  end
```

The group_post model looks like this with line 9 having the following code has_attached_file :photo :-

class GroupPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_comments
  belongs_to :investor_group
  validates_presence_of :message

#include Paperclip
  require "paperclip"
   # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :photo # line 9

end

Part of my view file where I am trying to upload the picture along with a post looks like this:-

```
<%form_for  :group_post, @group_post, :url => {:action => :show},:html => {:multipart => 'true'},:id => 'new_post' do |f| -%>
    <p><label>Start Discussion:</label><br><%=f.text_field :message%></p>
   <%=f.file_field :photo%></p> 
   <p><%=submit_tag "Post"%></p>
  <%end%>
```

I tried what was given in:-

- [Why do I get an "undefined method for `has_attached_file` when installing PaperClip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661062/installing-paperclip-undefined-method-has-attached-file-for-ruby-on-rails/3373493#3373493)

This option didn't seem applicable to my case as it seems to be using a
   higher Rails version

- [Undefined method has_attached_file after Paperclip installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886088/undefined-method-has-attached-file-after-paperclip-installation)

  I tried restarting my server, but it didn't solve my problem;
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/192

I tried the include Paperclip - but it really didn't seem to help my case...

I have added a require in my group_post.rb and in my environment.rb file as require "paperclip". I still get an undefined method error. I don't know why..

- [NoMethodError: undefined method `has_attached_file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743902/nomethoderror-undefined-method-has-attached-file)

On referring to this I tried Imumar's fork of paperclip, I manually pasted it in my vendor/plugins directory after git cloning it.. I got the following error( I have a feeling there surely would have been a dependency issue as his version might be compatible only with a higher rails version:

```
mohnish@mohnish-desktop:~/UP/dev$ ruby script/server -p 4000
=> Booting Mongrel (use 'script/server webrick' to force WEBrick)
=> Rails application starting on http://0.0.0.0:4000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:4000
** Starting Rails with development environment...
Exiting
/home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:263:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Paperclip::CallbackCompatability::Rails20 (NameError)
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:118:in `included'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:364:in `include'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:364:in `send'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:364
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/vendor/plugins/paperclip/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:79:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:75:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:39:in `load'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:33:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:32:in `each'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:32:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:189:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:105:in `process'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:49:in `send'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /home/mohnish/UP/dev/config/environment.rb:16
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
mohnish@mohnish-desktop:~/UP/dev$
```

I really wonder where I am going wrong..

Any suggestions/insights would be highly appreciated. This is urgent for me as I have a deployment due, I would be really glad to get prompt answers/responses..

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, firstly, just to cover the "obvious" base: do "ls vendor/plugins" just to make sure that some version of paperclip is actually in your plugins directory and is therefore reachable by your application.

Secondly - the "require paperclip" in the *model* seems wrong to me. I'm guessing that require should go in your environment instead. Try putting it at the end of config/environments.rb instead.

Thirdly (and maybe unrelated to your specific problem) - 2.0.2 is a really old version of rails. If you can I'd upgrade to 2.3.5, or at the very least, 2.2.x. For all we know - you could have a problem because you've got a new version of paperclip and an old version of rails... this does sometimes make a difference.

A lot of the other links you posted are referring to installations up to Rails3 - the solutions to their problems will be different to yours for that reason.

Comment: - Your pretty much right.."you've got a new version of paperclip and an old version of rails..." is what was my exact problem.. to fix it I had to use a paperclip plugin of 8may08 commit from github..got this fixed.. about a week back actually... posted a similar question where I got a similar answer/solution to yours..Thanks...:)

Comment: No probs. Glad you got it sorted eventually :)

Answer (score 11):

Slightly related, decided to put this here for future googlers.

Using Rails 2.3.14 on Ruby 1.8.7 with bundler. As suggested by thoughtbot I'm using paperclip 2.7, i.e. my gemfile contains:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.7.0"
```

I was also receiving the "undefined method" error. What fixed it for me was to drop a `paperclip.rb`file into `config/initializers`containing the following:

```
require "paperclip/railtie"
Paperclip::Railtie.insert
```

Hopefully this will save someone a bit of headache.

Comment: fixes this issue for me, I am using rails 3.2.11 and paperclip 3.4.0

Comment: fixed my woes also, on ancient Rails 2.3.18 project with Paperclip 2.7.5